# What is the wordpress way of displaying local external content?

Tags: redirect, page-template, slug

I have a somewhat tricky situation. A company's internal server, running some unknown software (means I have no access whatsoever), exports data to my http server via a custom API. This data gets stored in the same MySQL environment as Wordpress. Just a different DB. Meaning DB1 has the WP data, DB2 holds the imported company data.

Now I need to display the imported data in WP. I'm having no problems displaying all data in a kind of overview. I just have a WP page, that in it's template compiles all the data from the DB and displays a list of all objects.

https://example.com/objects/all-objects

But how would I go about it, displaying **one** data object? I can't create a WP page for each data object. These change too fast, to keep up, and that constant adding and deleting would probably confuse the hell out of WP.

If I created an empty page "details", which would require an ID of what object to display, that might work:

[https://example.com/objects/details/[object-ID]](https://example.com/objects/details/%5Bobject-ID%5D)

Then I could, in the template of page "details", read the object-ID from the URL and display the requested data.

---

**Question is:**

How can I make sure, this causes no problems with loading the right template, not showing 404, etc ? Is there some function in WP, that would make sure, that "details" gets loaded, no matter what follows the URL-slug?

**What is the Wordpress way, of accomplishing this?**

I keep banging my head against the wall, I guess I'm just missing the right keywords to look for...

Thanks for all hints and help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're looking for exactly.  But in my estimation, maybe this will help you move in the right direction.

I think what you want is a URL rewrite so you can have a URL endpoint that results in your data being displayed.  If you work in the right conditional logic, you can avoid a 404 and display an error message instead.

First, you need tell WP that [object-ID] is a query arg.  For sake of example, we'll call that variable `$my_object_id` (I'd make sure you have some prefix before "object_id" simply to avoid potential name collisions with other less detailed variable names).

To add your "object ID" as a custom query var you can use in the URL, use the `query_vars` filter:

```
function my_object_id_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my_object_id';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_object_id_query_var' );
```

Now you can pick that up with `get_query_var()`:

```
$object_id = get_query_var( 'my_object_id' );
```

So now you want to be able to use that in your URL.  Use `add_rewrite_rule()` to add these to your possible permalink structure:

```
function my_object_id_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^my_object_id/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?my_object_id=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_object_id_rewrite_tag_rule' );
```

Note that you'll likely need to refresh your permalink settings - just resave your existing settings.

Then, if your object ID value is "some_id", you should be able to get it from the url like this:

[https://example.com/objects/details/my_object_id/{actual_object_id}/](https://example.com/objects/details/my_object_id/%7Bactual_object_id%7D/)

Note that this answer is likely to take some additional tinkering on your part - it's not going to fly right out of the box.  But I think that adding a rewrite rule is the direction you're headed.  Hope this helps.

**Update:**

Based on the comments, I think the following may be closer to what you need to use:

```
// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it 
function SH_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
  array_push( $vars, 'SH_objekt_id' );
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'SH_insert_query_vars' );

// define rewrite rule 
function SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^SH_objekt_id/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=860&SH_objekt_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule' );
```

The URL then would be:

[https://example.com/objects/details/SH_objekt_id/{actual_object_id_value}/](https://example.com/objects/details/SH_objekt_id/%7Bactual_object_id_value%7D/)

(Note how the query var is used in the URL)

Now in your template, the following should pick up the object ID value:

```
$object_id = get_query_var( 'SH_objekt_id' );
```

**Update #2 (what ended up working for the OP after working out the details):**

User needed to change some details for a specific URL. These are noted in the comments and summarized here for ease of reading the code.

```
// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it 

function SH_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
  array_push( $vars, 'objekt_id' );
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'SH_insert_query_vars' );

// define rewrite rule 

function SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^vermietung/wohnobjekte/details-wohnobjekt/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=860&objekt_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule' );
```

Note that now the query var needs to be retrieved as `get_query_var( 'objekt_id' )`

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! So essentially, I put these snippets in the template for "details"? So that on all other pages it doesn't start to look for IDs?

Comment: Ah, and since we have this nice regex in `add_rewrite_tag()`, I could also specify to look for integer numbers, since all my IDs are integers. So I could also put these functions into `functions.php` of the "details"-template, right?

Comment: Anyway, you set me on the right track, I think! I'm just studying https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/ This looks, like I was looking for this! Thanks again!

Comment: I would put this in a custom plugin or your theme's functions.php file.  I wouldn't put it in the template because otherwise it won't load when you need it to load.  In other words, your setup needs what's in these snippets to know that the rewrite rule and the query var are.  It needs those to know to load your specific template (if that's how you choose to handle display). So if you put these in that template, you've got the logic order in reverse.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! Thanks! I put this stuff into functions.php. I've been fiddeling around with that for some time now, and I can't seem to get it to work. `get_query_var()` always returns nothing. So I guess, sth is wrong with my implemetation. I suspect that `add_rewrite_rule()` may be the culprit, esp. the regex. Where is the regex part, that defines that I want the last part of the uri and only the numbers?

Comment: functions.php: `// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function SH_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'SH_objekt_id' );
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'SH_insert_query_vars' );

// define rewrite rule
function SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%SH_objekt_id%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^SH_objekt_id/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=860&SH_objekt_id=$group[1]','top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0 );`

Comment: details template: `$objekt_id = intval(get_query_var('SH_objekt_id')); print_r($objekt_id); // returns 0`

Comment: The live query string would be sth like `/vermietung/wohnobjekte/details-wohnobjekt/71674/` where `details-wohnobjekt` is the page with the corresponding template (`page_id=680`).

Comment: I apologize for one place I steered you astray. Note the URL. This needs to include the query_var itself. I updated the answer above accordingly.  Next, and also important, don't change `$matches` to `$group` in the rewrite rule - leave it as `$matches`. Lastly, once you implement this, you need to flush your rewrite rules so the new rule is added when the rules are refreshed.  To do that, just go to your permalinks settings and resave the page (no need to change any settings - just resave what you have).

Comment: No need to apologise! Thanks for the update! So you removed the `add_rewrite_tag()` altogether. Trouble is, now the URL doesn't match! It matches with: `https://example.com/SH_objekt_id/{actual_object_id_value}/`. How can I make it work with `https://example.com/objects/details/{actual_object_id_value}/`?

Comment: This is the best, I could come to a regex on my own: `^\/vermietung\/wohnobjekte\/details-wohnobjekt\/([^\/]*)\/?` regex101.com says that gives 2 matches: Match 1: `/vermietung/wohnobjekte/details-wohnobjekt/71674/`, Group 1: `71674` So, group 1 is, what I'm trying to get into the `add_rewrite_rule()`, right?

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: For the record, in functions.php now is: `// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function SH_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
  array_push( $vars, 'objekt_id' );
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'SH_insert_query_vars' );

// define rewrite rule
function SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^vermietung/wohnobjekte/details-wohnobjekt/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=860&objekt_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'SH_objekt_id_rewrite_tag_rule' );` I messed up the query_vars part, the regex was actually working! :-$

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get the original suggestion to a point that worked for you.  I added an update with the code in your comment so it's easier to read for anyone that comes by this later.

Comment: You're a life-saver! Thanks again! *all thumbs up* :)